# Force JSON format using CakePHP 3 and Crud plugin

Tags: cakephp, crud, cakephp-3.0

I have followed [How to build a CakePHP 3 REST API](http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-build-a-cakephp-3-rest-api-in-minutes/) tutorial to create REST API. Tutorial describes case when requests are made with extensions (json/xml) to set response format. Plugin [CRUD for CakePHP](http://crud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contents.html) is used.

I want to force JSON response format **without using .json extension**. I am getting MissingRouteException on my requests.

**What have I tried**

```
Router::prefix('api', function ($routes) {
    //$routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);
    $routes->resources('Cocktails');
});
```

plus

**#1**

`$this->RequestHandler->ext = 'json'` into AppController::beforeFilter()

**#2**

`$this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');` into AppController::beforeFilter()

but this is trying to use template from `Template/Api/Coctails/json`

I want it to behave exactly like in the case with extension.

Thanks

Comment: Request your data with a proper HTTP accept header, the RequestHandler should pick it up then. See http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-the-accept-and-content-type-http-headers

Comment: It works, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request your data with [a proper HTTP accept header](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-the-accept-and-content-type-http-headers)  `Accept: application/json`, the RequestHandler should pick it up then.

> The Accept header is used by HTTP clients to tell the server what
>   content types they'll accept. The server will then send back a
>   response, which will include a Content-Type header telling the client
>   what the content type of the returned content actually is.
>
> However, as you may have noticed, HTTP requests can also contain
>   Content-Type headers. Why? Well, think about POST or PUT requests.
>   With those request types, the client is actually sending a bunch of
>   data to the server as part of the request, and the Content-Type header
>   tells the server what the data actually is (and thus determines how
>   the server will parse it).
>
> In particular, for a typical POST request resulting from an HTML form
>   submission, the Content-Type of the request will normally be either
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data.